# Como remover o atributo UNIQUE KEY de uma coluna no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Criei uma tabela no MySQl que utiliza uma coluna chamada `loja_num` com o atributo *unique key*

```
UNIQUE KEY loja_num (loja_num,
```

Mas agora, eu gostaria de retirar esse atributo dessa coluna. Já fiz umas pesquisas sem sucesso. Alguém sabe me informar qual comando utilizo no MySQL?

Utilizo XAMPP no Windows e o banco de dados é MySQL.

Obrigado.

Comment: Pessoal, esquece!!! Foi resolvido da seguinte maneira: 

1) Pesquisei quais eram os INDEXES que existiam no banco:
'SHOW INDEXES FROM lojas_info;'

Depois deletei o INDEX que continha a UNIQUE KEY:
'ALTER TABLE lojas_info
  DROP INDEX loja_num;'

Comment: Se você já achou a solução, poste uma resposta à sua própria pergunta.

Comment: @IgorSantana seria legal você postar a solução na resposta, assim ajudaria futuros visitantes com a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Mas eu postei ali em cima ..... veja:

1) Pesquisei quais eram os INDEXES que existiam no banco: 'SHOW INDEXES FROM lojas_info;' Depois deletei o INDEX que continha a UNIQUE KEY: 'ALTER TABLE lojas_info DROP INDEX loja_num;'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O próprio [@IgorSantana](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/55183/igor-santana) comentou a resolução da seguinte forma:

1. Pesquisou quais eram os indexes que existiam no banco.

   ```
   SHOW INDEXES FROM lojas_info;
   ```
2. Deletou o index que continha a `UNIQUE KEY`:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE lojas_info DROP INDEX loja_num;
   ```

Comment: Opa... foi isso mesmo! obrigado... eu ainda estou me acostumando a este forum! obrigado! :D